# DocBook Generation for HTML help page: How to?

Tags: html, xslt, docbook, docbook-5, docbook-xsl

I've been reading DocBook Documentation but I don't really get to understand how to do it.

If you see this website, they contain just what I want, a treeview and a search index, it's using the same documentation for that tool, webdocs for DocBook.

http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/webhelp/docs/ch01.html

I have a json string as:

```
[
  {
   "widget":"MyWidget",
   "description":"A description here",
   "requires":["list","of","requeriments"],
   "data":{
            "name":"the name of the widget",
            "height":"the height of the widget"
          }
  },
  .... more widgets
]
```

And I need to transform that to DocBook, just the same way it was shown in the link I gave; however each time I read a page on tutorials and documentation they change everything it requires, the programs I should use, the product. So I'm quite confused.

Just give me a small example on what programs should I `sudo apt-get install`, and how a book from the data above should look in DocBook's format, (just an example book).

I've heard that DocBooks can be converted into an html, multiple-html, and chm; I want single html.

Comment: *And I need to transform that to DocBook*. Then you need to to it yourself. DocBook sources are XML files. There is no tool that I know of that automatically transforms JSON to the DocBook flavour of XML.

Comment: @mzjn I surely know I have to do that myself, I'm just somewhat confused about the DocBooks syntax for the purpose I want

Comment: http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/webhelp/docs/ch01.html

Comment: What do you mean by "*they change everything it requires*". Who does that?

Comment: Each time I read a tutorial, about DocBook they say it requires some sort of xstl framework, then I read another and says its requirement is eclipse ant, the next one talks about pdf, even latex. So I get confused because it's like replacing one utility with other that doesn't even do the same thing to expect the same thing.

Comment: And what I want is something as that link shows (it's made with DocBook) and they even explain how to, but I'm very confused now, I just need a guide on how to start all this formatting.

Comment: It seems like you are asking two different questions: 1) Can I represent JSON structures in DocBook XML? (Btw, even if the answer is yes, there may be other options. Here is a related question with several suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953692/syntax-for-documenting-json-structure). 2) Once I have my DocBook XML content, what do I need to do in order to generate nice HTML (WebHelp) output from it?