# Python formating JSON inside a docstring

Tags: python, json, documentation

Hello i'm trying to create a docstring like this in Python:

```
    def hello_world_request(self, json):
    """
    foo
    Example JSON:
    
    {
        "helloWorld": [
            {
                "firstWord": "Hello",
                "lastWord": "World",
                "comment": "foo"
            }
        ]
    }

    :param json: json object
    """
```

Looking at the image below you can see the documentation. Is it possible to have each line in the docstring also show as a separate line in the documentation? So it looks like the docstring of the function.

[image: documentation being compressed example]

Comment: Did you tried entering another white line between fields? Btw you can check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953692/syntax-for-documenting-json-structure

Comment: Adding a newline between the firstWord and  lastWord works, however, this feels like a hack and not the intended way.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out

```
   """
    foo
     .. code-block:: json

    {
        "helloWorld": [
            {
                "firstWord": "Hello",
                "lastWord": "World",
                "comment": "foo"
            }
        ]
    }

    :param json: json object
    """
```